# Installing an old version of boot clj

Tags: linux, version, boot-clj

How to install the old version of boot clj? I would need a 2.7.2 version but actually a 2.8.3 is being installed. My OS is Debian 9.

Answer (score 0):

The way is to put a file `boot.properties`:

```
#http://boot-clj.com
#Mon Jan 18 23:19:36 CET 2016
BOOT_CLOJURE_NAME=org.clojure/clojure
BOOT_CLOJURE_VERSION=1.8.0
BOOT_VERSION=2.7.2
BOOT_EMIT_TARGET=no
```

or similar into a project folder and run `boot` command in it.